# Journey Builder Flow Control Based on New or Existing Data Extension Record

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cloudpage

Is there a way to control a journey's flow based on if the record is new or an existing Specifically, I'm using a Cloud Page form as an entry source.

Here's my use case: A user fills out a Cloud Page form and clicks submit. My existing journey sends them an email thanking them for subscribing. However, if the user already exists, and they fill out the form again, I would like to send them a different email notifying them that they've updated their info.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do it in several approaches but here is my suggestion:

1. Create two new nullable Boolean fields in the Entry Source Data Extension, let's call them `FormSubmitted` and `FormUpdated`
2. Add the logic on the CloudPage that once the form is submitted, you populate one of these fields with `True` value. So it going to be if `FormSubmitted` is empty, then populate it with `True` value and if already populated then `FormUpdated` gets `True` value -

```
%%[
/* You need to identify the SubscriberKey in advance though */
SET @Lookup = Lookup("Entry_Source_DE", "FormSubmitted", "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)

IF EMPTY(@Lookup) THEN
    SET @UpdateData = UpdateData("Entry_Source_DE", 1, "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey, "FormSubmitted", "True")
ELSE
    SET @UpdateData = UpdateData("Entry_Source_DE", 1, "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey, "FormUpdated", "True")
ENDIF
]%%
```

3. Next, in the Journey, you add Decision Split, which would split the audience into two paths: first one - `FormSubmitted = True` and second one `FormUpdated = True` (remember to create an Attribute Group with the Entry Source Data Extension in advance)
4. Add different Email Activities into each path, where `FormSubmitted = True` is for first submitters and `FormUpdated = True` is for contacts that submitted at least twice.

Some documentation links - AMPscript [Lookup](https://ampscript.guide/lookup/) and [UpdateData](https://ampscript.guide/updatedata/) functions and then how to set up [Dicision Split](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_use_decision_splits.htm&type=5) in the Journey.

Comment: + remember to choose the contact data instead of journey data while adding decision split

Comment: This may be another question to submit, but what if I only want to display a message on the landing page for records that already exist (no email/journey), and send an email for new records?

Comment: Then again you would have some AMPscript that would work via Lookup into the Entry Source DE to see if the record already exists and based on the result display needed message. You would wrap your ‘HTML’ with AMPscript IF, ELSE, ENDIF conditions.

Comment: I placed the lookup and update code above the <HTML> tag of the landing page and  an error was returned. I did try a simple variable and that worked, but for some reason the lookup code does not work. I've updated lookup and update arguments with my specific DE.